# applied trigonometry: joining angles for two adjoining boards

Tags: trigonometry

I have a trigonometic problem, as much “applied science” as it gets. (so please forgive me for asking such trivia)

I am doing wall-mounted wooden boards, made out of two planks, sitting in a corner of the room adjoined at a 45° angle. In side view they are 90° to the wall, as you would expected. Lets call this *regular* with a tilt angle of $\alpha=0°$:

[image]

More recently I started to slightly tilting them against a wall (so books and toys will fall off less easily), i.e. at an angle of $\alpha=5°$.

1. **In dependency of $\alpha$, how do I calculate the angle $\beta$ (in regular design 45°)?** ($\beta$ will need to grow larger than $45°$, otherwise I will have an opening gap like a draw brige…)
2. **In dependency of $\alpha$, how do I calculate the trim angle $\gamma$ at which to cut my boards** (see figure (2). How much do I need to tilt my saw blade, will have to be more “pointy” than the 90° in regular design )

*(I believe, the (varying) lengths and (identical) depth of each planks does not matter and neither does thickness, if I am not mistaken. All angles measured on top surface.)*

Answer (score 1):

This post will probably get closed, I'm not sure if it meet the guidelines. Nevertheless, here's an attempt to help you with a basic mathematical problem involved in your woodworking.

[image: woodplank trim angle]

Carefully observe how the trim angle affects elevation of horizontal plank when you join them that way.

In the first diagram $\beta$ can be noticed to be equal to $45°$ and so, $x$ will be $135°$. When the plank is cut and joined, you can see how $2x$ makes $270°$.

Now you want to reduce this $270°$ angle, or, in other words, you want to increase that $2 \beta$, or, you want to increase $\alpha$ from $0°$ to some positive angle $\alpha$

So, when your trim angle is $\gamma$ you get the sideview angle (which was earlier $\beta +\beta=90°$) equal to $\gamma+ \gamma=2\gamma$

For angle of elevation $\alpha$ from $0°$, you need $2\gamma= 90°+\alpha\;$,

i.e. ,  $\gamma=45°+\frac{\alpha}2$

Comment: At a trim angle of $\gamma= 90°$, you get the sideview angle, $180°$ (tilt angle, $\alpha =90°$). As, you decrease $\gamma$ by unit degree the side view angle gets decreased by $2°$. For $\gamma>45°$, you get positive tilt angle which you called $\alpha$, for $\gamma<45°$, you will get negative $\alpha$, i.e.,  instead of holding toys, it will make them slide off.